# "Echad mi yodeya" describing merits for Exodus -- source?

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada, song-poetry, yetziat-mitzrayim, artscroll

The Artscroll Family Hagadah explains that Echad Mi Yodeya is asking "in what merit were the Jews redeemed from Egypt?" Well, they believed in one God, they would receive two tablets, they had great ancestors, and so on ... "nine are the months before a baby's born" -- they kept having babies and carrying pregnancies to term, even when things looked bleak.

That last point feels somewhat, well, modern. Is there an earlier commentary that says this, or was this an insight of the Artscroll authors?

Answer (score 2):

The general point is made [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ha4pAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q&f=false) in a Haggada printed in 1907. It doesn't give its source, and doesn't specifically point out how the 9 months fits. Regarding pregnancy, specifically, this is in the [Talmud Sotah 11b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=11b&format=pdf), although I suppose the emphasis on "carrying pregnancies to term", as opposed to just working to have babies, could be a bit of editorializing by Artscroll itself.